# Windbg ProcessUptime is not equal to Kernel Time + User Time

Tags: windows, windbg

I was analyzing mini-dump of one of my processes using Windbg. I used .time command to see the process time and I got the result as below. I was expecting (Process Uptime = Kernel Time + User Time), which was not the case. Does any body know why or my interpretation is wrong?

```
0:035> .time
Debug session time: Tue May  5 14:30:24.000 2020 (UTC - 7:00)
System Uptime: not available
Process Uptime: 3 days 5:29:22.000
  Kernel time: 0 days 9:06:26.000
  User time: 11 days 18:50:47.000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The kernel & user times match the CPU / Kernel & User Times displayed in [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) under the Performance tab, and are likely related to the times returned by [GetProcessTimes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getprocesstimes). They add up to the Total Time displayed in Process Explorer, or the CPU Time displayed in Task Manager for the same process.

This "CPU time" is the total time across *all* CPUs, and does *not* include time the process spent sleeping, waiting, or otherwise sitting idle. Because of that it can be either (a) smaller than the process "uptime" which is simply the time difference between the start and end times, in the case of mostly idle processes, or (b) larger than the process uptime in the case of heavy usage across multiple CPUs.